# Xamarin forms how to use custom ui in Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have extended the label class to create a slightly different piece of UI and would rather add it to my page with XAML rather than C# code. How can I do this?

Code:

```
namespace M.Helpers
{
    public class LinkingLabel: Label
    {
        public LinkingLabel(Uri uri, String labelText = null)
        {
            Text = labelText ?? uri.ToString();
            TextColor = Color.Blue;
            GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer { Command = new Command(() => Device.OpenUri(uri)) });

        }
    }
}
```

How can I simply write `<LinkingLabel Uri="" Text=""></LinkingLabel>` inside of my pages XAML. I am getting errors but no intellisense to help me import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add namespace declaration attribute to the root tag in the XAML file:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:M.Helpers"
```

And, use it while declaring your custom control:

```
<controls:LinkingLabel Uri="" Text="">
...
</controls:LinkingLabel>
```

Also, because you don't have a default constructor in your custom control, you will need to pass in the arguments as parameters. More details [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/passing-arguments/).